# 'Response' does not contain a definition for 'Redirect'

Tags: c#, .net, saml, system.web

I am trying to use the AspNetSaml nuget package (https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml) and I am getting an error when trying to use the `Response.Redirect(url)` method.

This is the error:

> Error CS0117  'Response' does not contain a definition for 'Redirect'

I am already using the namespace `System.Web` and also I added the `System.Web.dll`

```
static void Redir(Response samlResponse)
{
    //specify the SAML provider url here, aka "Endpoint"
    var samlEndpoint = "https://saml.xxxx.com/idp/SSO.saml2";

    AuthRequest request = new AuthRequest(
        "https://www.xxxx.com/", //put your app's "unique ID" here
        "https://www.xxxx.com/" //assertion Consumer Url - the redirect URL where the provider will send authenticated users
        );

    // Generate the provider URL
    string url = request.GetRedirectUrl(samlEndpoint);

    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access a Page's `HttpResponse` object, from a static method. Make your method non static:

```
void Redir(Response samlResponse)
{
    ...
    this.Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace your function call

```
Redire(this.Response)
```

by

```
Response.Redirect(Redire())
```

With your Redire function returning the url to redirect to. This way you'll get out of the static context that create the problem here.